# Is there required any event handling inside didUpdateToLocation method when app is in background?

Tags: iphone, ios5, gps, xcode4.2, core-location

I am using core location framework inside my app and i added location string in UIBackgroundMode or Required background modes(in xcode 4.2) in info.plist to get updates about location when app also in background state. In documentation of this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html it is stated that UIBackgroundMode(location) will notify the app when location is update when app is in background. I think if app sleeps and location updates then app will be notified about location update and it goes to background state again am i correct? OR will we required any event handling inside didUpdateToLocation method when app is in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No event handling is required in didupdatelocation method. It will notify app when location is updated.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks means we are only required UIBackgroundMode(location) added to info.plist to get location updates also when app is in background and event handling is not required in didUpdateToLocation method am i correct?

Comment: yes by adding UIBackgroundMode=YES in plist - location delegate method will be called.